# Ubuntu : 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path

Tags: android, meteor

My android sdk path is : /home/iassureit-02/Android/sdk

.bash_profile file was not there so created the one with touch command and put below lines in it.

```
# Android
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/iassureit-02/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

After running meteor run android command I am getting below error:

```
✓ Java JDK                                    
✗ Android SDK: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path:
  /home/iassureit-02/Library/Android/sdk
  Try to update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
  is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.

  Looked here:
  /home/iassureit-02/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

Why is it looking for SDK in library folder?
I am not getting what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to export this environment variable in .bashrc if you find it ? Because if .bash_profile did not exist, your Pc may have his variables set to .bashrc. (mine did not have .bash_profile either, so I added it to .bashrc and it works).

Comment: PS : The sdk folder is the one with the "tools" and "platform-tools" folders, check if this is the case in your "/home/iassureit-02/Android/Sdk" folder :)